# How to install .diff file from arch linux wiki

Tags: linux, arch-linux, linux-kernel, snap

I downloaded [Ubuntu's Linux 4.4 patchset](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Snapd) from the arch wiki for snapd, it downloaded as a tar ball and after extracting it I go a directory name `linux_4.4.0-21.37.diff` with a files inside named `data, debugfs-aufs, namespace.txt and sysfs-aufs`, according to the arch wiki page for snapd the patch is required for the reason shown below

> Warning: snap-confine is built with the `--disable-apparmor` option; full confinement relies on an AppArmor enabled kernel with Ubuntu's Linux 4.4 patchset applied and a related profile for the snap.

I have had problems with snaps before and I think installing this patch will fix it, so can anyone please tell how to install this patch, Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The `diff` file is the output of the `diff` command which gives the differences between two (usually fairly similar) files. There is a command `patch`, which can take this list of differences and one version of the file and produce the other file.

Exactly how you invoke `patch` depends on how the `diff` was produced in the first place.

I would try `patch < /the/path/to/one/of/the/patch/files` first, and if that fails or produces error messages (hit ctrl-c if it asks questions) try again adding `-p1`. Otherwise show us the first few lines from the patch files.

Comment: this is my output after using the command on the `data` file
`$ patch < data`
`can't find file to patch at input line 3`
`Perhaps you should have used the -p or --strip option?`
`The text leading up to this was:`
`|--- linux-4.4.0.orig/Documentation/ABI/stable/sysfs-bus-vmbus`
`|+++ linux-4.4.0/Documentation/ABI/stable/sysfs-bus-vmbus`
`File to patch: `
What should I do now

Comment: when I use `$patch --help` and see the help of the '-p' and it says `-p NUM  --strip=NUM  Strip NUM leading components from file names` I need more explanation on this

Comment: The patch is trying to update a file called linux-4.4.0/Documentation/ABI/stable/sysfs-bus-vmbus so you want to be at the top of the Linux source tree if you are using -p1, i.e there should be a directory called Documentation when you type `ls`. I am assuming that you know you are going to be building your own kernel.

Answer (score 0):

First you need linux_4.4.0 source code.

For example, I have linux_4.4.0 source code in `/home/$USER/linux-4.4.0`,
and `linux_4.4.0-21.37.diff` in `/home/$USER`.

Enter the following command to automatically patch file

```
cd /home/$USER/linux-4.4.0
cat ../linux_4.4.0-21.37.diff | patch -p1
```